# What is the fallacy called - A occurs because B causes it then if !A means !B?

Tags: fallacies

For example, "You are rich because you are blessed (God blessed you with riches). If you are not rich then you must not be blessed (God chose not to bless you oh ye of little faith)."

Second example, "By the super secret law of attraction you can manifest riches in your life. If you don't have riches it is because you did not attract it into your life you stupid idiot. It's so easy. Do you hate money?"

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

Your two examples have different logical structures. So I will treat them separately.

## First example

**[Negating Antecedent and Consequent](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/132/Negating-Antecedent-and-Consequent)**
***(also known as improper transposition)***

The logical structure simply is:

A → B, therefore ¬A → ¬B

The fallacy lies in not switching antecedent and consequent. Therefore, it is the inverse rather than the contrapositive. It is only the contrapositive that is logically equivalent to the original proposition and therefore already implied in it. You can read more helpful links and thoughts explaining these terms and their differences in [this related answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/42957/17209).

## Second example and header

The header and the second example have another logical form. They correctly state the *implication* (NOT syllogism!)

A → B, therefore ¬B → ¬A

But the validity (or truth value) of this depends on the truth value of 'A → B'. Therefore, arguing along these lines without further support is **[begging the question](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/53/Begging-the-Question)** or *petitio principii*, as another answer correctly stated. It is a type of circular reasoning.

#### Explanation

Your second example basically argues that by attracting money, you become rich, and as you are not rich, you did not attract money. Here, you presuppose that it is only by attracting money you become rich, and from that, you gather the implication, the contrapositive. As both sides (before and after "therefore") are logically equivalent, it can be transformed into

A → B, therefore A → B

Or, if you like: X → X

It is like saying "There **IS** God, therefore there is God.", while thumping on the table. This is begging the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll look at the second example: "*By the super secret law of attraction you can manifest riches in your life. If you don't have riches it is because you did not attract it into your life you stupid idiot. It's so easy. Do you hate money?*"

The first part is a completely unproven conjecture. The conjecture is: "There is a super secret law of attraction which could be used by anybody to manifest riches in their lives". It's just that - a conjecture. Why would anybody believe that it is true?

The middle part is a conclusion: "If you don't have riches it is because you did not attract it into your life." Actually, that's not a fallacy. If part 1 were true, which it isn't, then the conclusion would be correct. Since part 1 is not true, this conclusion is worthless.

Then we have an insult, "you stupid idiot". Seems like a rather pathetic attempt to preemptively insult anyone who is going to contradict the conclusion. "It's so easy". Come on. If it was possible to attract riches into your life, and if it was easy, everyone would do it. So we have good evidence that it is *not* easy. "Do you hate money?" That's another insult, intented to enable an ad hominem attack to anyone daring to contradict the speaker. The speaker tries to display the person as an irrational human being.

So there is no logical fallacy here really. But there is plenty wrong: Making bold unproven assumptions, and telling us to believe them without any reason. Insulting the careful listener to weaken their arguments.

Comment: -1 Because you did not answer the question: 1.) The question was whether there occurs a fallacy or not. Assuming a super secret law is logically correct; hence the discussion whether one should believe this is superfluous and leads you (and the ones that upvoted you erroneously) to miss the forest for the trees: You say "there is no logical fallacy here really", not seeing the 'poisoning of the well' or the 'argumentum ad hominem' though you speak about them phenomenologically -- and, strangely, they are right under your nose.

Comment: You don't address the first example, which does not fit into this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Lawrence suggested in an early version of his answer that your examples involve the logical fallacy of "affirming the consequent". However, that's incorrect.

["Affirming the consequent"](http://www.skepdic.com/affirmingtheconsequent.html) would be a fallacy like this :

1. If you're born into money, you're rich
2. You're rich
3. Therefore, you must be born into money

The reason that's a logical fallacy, is because there can be many reasons for being rich :

- You were born into money
- You invested in a company that became very profitable overnight
- You won the lottery
- You had just the right connections to team up with for your business
- You were lucky to start the right business at the right time
- ...

What happens here, is that you assume a cause because that cause happens to lead to a certain consequence. However, by doing so, you ignore all other possible causes!

That argument is not equivalent to your argument; however. Your argument kinda goes like this :

1. If you're born into money, you're rich
2. You're not rich
3. Therefore, you must not be born into money

This would actually be a correct assumption of being born into money automatically results to being rich. However, it doesn't. You can be born into money and not being rich.

Suppose that you are not rich. Does that mean that you were not born into money? Well, no. Maybe you were born into money, but you lost it all with bad investments or gambling.

Or does that mean that you don't have the right connections? Well, no. Maybe you have the right connections, but you prefer to be an employee rather than starting your own business.

etc. etc.

So if B is caused by A, the lack of B does not imply a lack of A per se, because there might actually be a C that prevents A from leading to B... or a C + D + E...

Real life is far, far, far more complex than every single event being directly caused by an individual previous event or prevented by the lack of an individual previous event. Real life is multi-dimensional, and everything that happens is literally the consequence of an intricate convergence trillions upon trillions of other events that happened before it and that are all entangled and entwined with each other!

I don't think the issue here is a logical fallacy, but merely an oversimplification on how causality works!

Comment: The problem in the first case is not about multiple reasons for being rich, it is about ways other than being rich to have been blessed.  If being rich is  the only way to be blessed, even if there are other ways of being rich, not being rich means you were not blessed.

Comment: @Lawrence : I don't think "begging the question" applies either. Anyway, I modified my answer.

Comment: @jobermark : Are there other ways to have been blessed? Are you sure?
 What is a "blessing" anyway? It seems to me to be something religious people made up a long time ago as a religious equivalent of "luck", but it kinda has no real meaning to me... which is why I avoided to use that particular example ;-)

Comment: The nonsesical nature of the premises do not affect the logic involved.  What you are saying here does not apply to the stated case.  It applies to the opposite direction of implication.  If you do not intend to read what is written before objecting, don't bother responding.

Comment: @jobermark : The logic applied, is "if (1) A -> B and (2) !B then (3) !A". I gave a real life use case of that argument as close as possible to the imaginary use case in the original question (I'm sorry, but the concept of "being blessed" is just something primitive people made up) and tried to explain what' the problem with that real life use case. The same logic I applied to that real life use case can be applied to the imaginary one : in both cases, the problem is an oversimplification of how causality works since the assumption that A always implies B is wrong!

Comment: @jobermark : (continued) Anyway, your comments seem to suggest that you didn't even bother to read my entire answer. The first part of my answer was addressing an answer by Lawrence (that he's modified since I posted my answer, which is why I removed the reference to Lawrence's answer). I explain thereafter how the issue is NOT that there's multiple reasons for being rich but that being born into money does not imply being rich per se... which is equivalent to your argument that being blessed does not imply being rich per se. Please read an answer completely before you comment on it!

Comment: @jobermark : (continued) I added the reference to Lawrence answer again, which - I guess - makes it less confusing that I start with arguing why "affirming the consequent" does NOT apply... I'm pretty sure the reference to Lawrence's question was still there when you made your original comment, though, so you can't use that as an excuse for jumping to conclusions ;-)

Comment: 'Your premise is trash' is not a logical fallacy.  There is something wrong with the actual *logic* unrelated to the complexity of stating a premise correctly.

Comment: @jobermark : If being rich would always follow from being blessed or being born into money, not being rich would imply not being blessed and not being born into money. That means the logic applied actually IS correct... which is why this isn't a logical fallacy... which you acknowledged yourself!

Comment: Yes, but there is an answer that does not just attack the premise.  By this logic almost no argument is ever valid, because we generally overstate premises.  Premises almost always miss the element of time, the ability to contradict them just because one is aware of them, the statistical nature of observation, or some other aspect that means they can only be reasoned from to a limited degree.  But in his formulation, there is a genuine semantic gap that leaves open an entirely unrelated interpretation of the premise.  Semantics is still related to logic.

Comment: I am tired of having you just ignore me and accuse me of things.  Goodbye.

Comment: @jobermark : Semantics is totally unrelated to logic IMO. Anyway, in what way am I ignoring you or "accusing you of things"?

Answer (score 1):

It's called *begging the question*.

> To **beg a question** means to assume the conclusion of an argument—a type of circular reasoning. This is an informal fallacy, in which an arguer includes the conclusion to be proven within a premise of the argument, often in an indirect way such that its presence within the premise is hidden or at least not easily apparent.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)

It's not always the case that the natural-language pattern *B causes A* translates fully to the logic statement *B -> A*. But if we accept the mapping for sake of discussion, then the deductive step itself is simply taking the contrapositive and therefore sound: *B -> A, therefore !A -> !B*.

The problem with the two natural-language examples in your question is that in each case, "A occurs because B causes it" hasn't been established. It is simply assumed, and a conclusion is derived from that assumption.

Let X = "*B causes A*" and Y = "*!A -> !B*".

Then the argument is "X, therefore Y". But since X and Y are logically equivalent, *if someone doesn't already accept Y* then it makes for a weak argument to prove Y by simply *assuming* X. In your examples, if the statements of causation aren't already accepted as axiomatically true, then they don't help establish the respective deductions.

Comment: -1, The OP's question is a (though paradox) example of modus tollens (= contraposition), which is logically sound as you rightly say. Hence it cannot be "affirming the consequent" as you claim.

Comment: @Zeus I've changed my answer to match the question.

Comment: @Zeus, it is only logically sound if it is appropriately strengthened by the assumption that open quantification is fully universal.  But this is optional in English.  "Diabetes happens because insulin resistance causes it" is true as an ordinary English statement, but it can mean three different things -- that insulin resistance is the only cause, that diabetes is always its effect, or both.  Only the second one is actually true.

Comment: @jobermark This all is not so important. I think that you focus too much on detail questions and in consequence lose the overall context, which is much more important than tiny details and special cases. This is the antagonism synthetic/analytic. I had just finished a long comment to “liquidate” your answer when I received your above comment. So, please read the new comment below your answer that I will post in a few minutes.

Comment: @Zeus  It is not your place to determine where I should focus.  Facts are facts whether they are picayune or grand.  There is no need to diagnose me.

Comment: Lawrence, 1.) You think that this is ‘begging the question’ because the law is not sure. Concerning the alleged uncertainty of these laws, see my “liquidation” of @jobermark's answer, in the [comments, part 3](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/44942/26880). I think that the intention of the question (of the OP) was not to challenge the laws, otherwise the whole additional scenery would be nonsensical. …

Comment: … 2.) “...since one would normally not argue that !A caused !B” -- Of course not, one would naturally write: **!A, hence no cause B**. -- Further: “... even if they held that A caused B.” This sentence is nonsensical since you speak about B caused A.

Comment: @Zeus To #1, the question seems to stem from disquiet about the natural-language examples. I've now addressed this more clearly in my answer. To #2, that was an inadvertent mistake on my part, now corrected.

Comment: @Lawrence: "But since X and Y are logically equivalent, if someone doesn't already accept Y then it makes for a weak argument to prove Y by simply assuming X." -- I cannot grasp what you mean by this sentence. I think that it is wrong. …

Comment: … I suggest to rewrite the whole thing without X and Y. Can you not write it down entirely (i.e. the whole post) in normal language (without A, B, X, Y, !A etc.)? – Anyway, I think that it is a bad thing to try to improve posts that didn't operate at the first onset. It's useless as demonstrated [by this extreme example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/74879/45298) with 17 edits up to the point of exhaustion. Now I normally just abandon them to their fate.

Answer (score 1):

**The title of the question is not a fallacy, but the two examples are fallacious versions of argumentum ad hominem or of poisoning the well.**

If these laws (blessing by God as condition // the super secret law) are premised, the conclusion is correct according to [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).

However, both examples mentioned by the OP, additionally to modus tollens, concern sectarian, denatured bookkeeping laws or ideologies. Ideologies intend to colonize men, trying to [morally or intellectually (--> part 1, § 3)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/44813/26880) manipulate them by ‘poisoning the well’ or by fallacious *variants* of ‘argumentum ad hominem’. This is the reason why the overall argumentations in the two examples become fallacies and confusing.

The occurring fallacious variants of argumentum ad hominem are the following:

- Little faith leads to not being blessed (--> fallacious argumentum ad hominem, insinuating “little faith” as personal character defect).
- If one does (for any reason) not (want to?) apply (or believe in) the super secret law, one is an “idiot” (--> fallacious argumentum ad hominem, insinuating a mental defect).

In both cases the well is poisoned, too, because the position of these persons has been shocked in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fallacy here.  The primary pitfall here is not one of logic, but one of semantics.

In abstract terms, your title describes a correct deduction.  If A **only** occurs because B **always** causes it, then when A does not occur, B must not have happened.  In an indicative mood, if we are being perfectly careful, this is what we mean, because we have "open quantification".  Unfortunately, English does not make that a rule, because the subjunctive markers in English have evolved into a useless mess, and can therefore be omitted at any time.

You can make the statement without implying the **always**.  If B only sometimes causes A, then obviously in those cases when it fails to do this causing, you have B and not A.  But in that case, you *should* say B **may** cause it, not that it *does* cause it.

You can also make the statement without implying the **only**.  But in that case you *should* say A **may** be caused by B, not that it **is** caused by B.  It might occur for other reasons.  But that omission still allows you to deduce that if you don't have A, B wasn't there.

So this English statement can have three different meanings with very different logical implications.  You can only tell if you know your speaker is an absolute pedant, or by context.  And deduction in your title is only true for two of them.

This ambiguity is one way of seeing what is wrong with your first example.

> For example, "You are rich because you are blessed (God blessed you with riches). If you are not rich then you must not be blessed (God chose not to bless you oh ye of little faith)."

'You are rich because you are blessed' only means that riches is *one possible* effect of being blessed, not that they are *always* an effect.  Any blessing *may cause* riches, it is not true that every blessing *does cause* riches.  It can happen that one person is rich because he was blessed, but that another person would be blessed in a different way.

> Second example, "By the super secret law of attraction you can manifest riches in your life. If you don't have riches it is because you did not attract it into your life you stupid idiot. It's so easy. Do you hate money?"

This does not have either problem, the the modal is there to clarify.  So the claim really is that doing B will always cause A for you, and the deduction is valid.  But a valid deduction from a false premise is still no good.  Not really a problem of logic or semantics, just a problem of having the wrong facts.

Comment: -1// jobermark 1.) I do not see the sense of your **only** and **always**.  This is really strange, but this is your style... what you write is (for me) often nearly illegible, and I think it is because you do not really focus on the questions. — I am sure that the OP just means an ordinary implication B --> A. // 2.) The problem in the first example does not come from equivocation, since in the “law” it would be possible to write “one” instead of “you”. With that the second third of your answer also begins to disappear in a flash. …

Comment: I don't care.  I do not need your criticism, because a large number of people do not share your opinion of my posts.  They understand them.  It may be possible that we two can only write for different audiences, but the people who do understand what I have written, often find it to be true.

Comment: … Instead the ideological/religious mania slumbering within these religious/esoteric laws are the problem, not equivocation. // 3.) Now to the liquidation of the last third: For the second example you say: wrong facts. Which wrong facts? Have ideologies ever consisted of facts? It has been presumed as “law”, with the tacit assumption that it must and cannot be proved because it is a transcendent law. _This is the game of theology/religion/sectarians_. They work with these laws; how can you say they are “wrong”?

Comment: … If we discuss it as law, as indicated in the title, then we must change in the modus that this is the valid law. BTW example 1 and 2 are exactly identical cases. Just considering that Job had to wait long until Jehovah had tried him sufficiently, helps to see that these (transcendental) laws thereby rightly expounded make sense in the theological/religious/sectarian world view, without using fallacies (arg. ad hominem like “idiot” etc.), as occurring in the examples.  Patience is the clue! Hence, nothing is wrong with these laws as you claim.

Comment: the answer has also changed since you read it.  And you didn't bother to check.  So what you are saying in 2 is corrected.  This kind of consistent inattention is just as bothersome to me as my style is to you, but I do not pick it out.  I only bring it up now because you feel entitle to declare my way of doing things wrong, and you have your own faults.

Comment: You have already attacked me rather mercilessly at other points, and I am not open to your evaluation.  You don't like my work, it is 'grimly' logical and I deserve to be sworn at for insisting dictionaries work.  So what?